# Optional Binding in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to create an extension on Binding so I can unwrap and bind to the optional Binding.

I have the following code which I got from StackOverFlow.

```
extension Binding {

    static func ??<T>(lhs: Binding<Optional<T>>, rhs: T) -> Binding<T> {

        return Binding(
            get: { lhs.wrappedValue ?? rhs },
            set: { lhs.wrappedValue = $0 }
        )

    }
}
```

But I get following error:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

When you use the initializer of `Binding(...)`, it infers its type parameter to be `Value` (remember, `Binding` is itself a generic, and `Value` is its type parameter), so in effect it does this:

```
Binding<Value>(...)
```

but expects the return to be `Binding<T>`.

So, you can either explicitly use `Binding<T>(...)`, or just let the compiler infer it based on the return value of the function:

```
static func ??<T>(lhs: Binding<Optional<T>>, rhs: T) -> Binding<T> {
   .init(get { lhs.wrappedValue ?? rhs },
         set { lhs.wrappedValue = $0 })
}
```

Or, just use `Value` instead of `T`:

```
static func ??(lhs: Binding<Optional<Value>>, rhs: Value) -> Binding<Value> {
   Binding(get { lhs.wrappedValue ?? rhs },
           set { lhs.wrappedValue = $0 })
}
```